# How to use multiple lines of a data file in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with two columns: `Xi` and `Yi`. I'd like to plot `Xi` vs. `(Yi-1 - Yi)/Yi-1` for `i>1`. Is is possible to do that in GNUPlot direclty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible with gnuplot directly -- It's just not easy:

```
firstval = NaN
yi1(yi) = (returnval=firstval, firstval=yi, returnval)
plot "datafile" using 1:((yi1($2)-$2)/returnval)
```

You need to use inline functions.  inline functions are of the form:

```
funcname(args,...) = (statement1,statement2,...,statementn, return_value)
```

Here I just created a function to hold the last value it was passed.  Unforunately, this solution gets a little more ugly since I couldn't call `yi1` twice in the using specification (the second time, I would get the wrong return value), so I had to reference the variable holding the return value directly.  It's not pretty, but it works.  You could probably "pretty" it up a little bit by passing `$0` (the line number) and only updating when $0 changes, but it's probably not worth it for this hack.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in gnuplot directly is tricky. The problem is that you have to use the (i-1)th element in your calculation, which gnuplot can't do automatically. It can do simple calculations, but only on the same row, for example something like

```
plot "datafile" using ($1):(($2-$1)/$2)
```

would be easy.

For what you neet to do I'd recommend [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), or you could prepare your data file using a spreadsheet application.

In octave, you could plot this like:

```
d = load("datafile")
plot(d(2:end, 1), d(1:end-1, 2)-d(2:end, 2)./d(1:end-1, 2))
```

Comment: You can do this sort of thing if you want to with only gnuplot (see my solution), but it quickly becomes cumbersome if you want the i-2, or i-3 element.  And i+1 and i+2 elements cannot be retrieved (but that's not too much of a problem -- just shift your indexing :).

Comment: @mgilson - didn't think about such a solution :) the only problem I see is that you can't do a `replot` without reseting `firstval`

Comment: Definitely true -- Although I don't really find myself replotting very often these days.